# Finding density function of reciprocal of Rayleigh random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

I have a Rayleigh distributed random variable $X$. How can I find pdf of another random variable $Y= \frac{1}{X}$.

Using some knowedge of transformations I found that pdf of $Y$,  $f_Y(y) = \frac{-1}{x^2}f_X(\frac{1}{x^2})$, but I am not sure whether I am correct.

Comment: How did you do the transformation?

Comment: I wrote $F_Y(y) = 1-F_X(\frac{1}{x})$ and used differentiation w.r.t $y$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint.

The PDF is the derivative of CDF. By the definition of CDF
$$
P(Y\le y)=P(X\ge 1/y)=1-P(X<1/y)\quad y>0
$$

Now use the [Rayleigh distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution) assumption.

---

For your edited question, you make two mistake on the right: the variable should by $y$, not $x$; inside the density, you should use $\frac1y$.